# Export query as csv needs improvement

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am building a code which helps me retrieve the query and export it like a csv, it all works fine, but what id does is, if i go to the /query.php it downloads immediately the csv file, while i want to click for it to be downloaded.

Can you help me on how to do this?

This is the code..

```
  $query = sprintf( 'SELECT * FROM hostess' );
  $result = mysql_query( $query, $conn ) or die( mysql_error( $conn ) );

  header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
  header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv' );

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
  if ( $row )
  {
    echocsv( array_keys( $row ) );
  }

  while ( $row )
  {
    echocsv( $row );
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
  }

  function echocsv( $fields )
  {
    $separator = '';
    foreach ( $fields as $field )
    {
      if ( preg_match( '/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field ) )
      {
        $field = '"' . str_replace( '"', '""', $field ) . '"';
      }
      echo $separator . $field;
      $separator = ',';
    }
    echo "\r\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: This script isn't something i produced, reading online i found a solution to it..

Comment: @SalmanA Haha! I just looked it up. Interesting.....

Answer (score 3):

Create a page that contains a link to the CSV generation script.

## Edit

You can create a simple HTML form that passes parameters to the CSV script using query strings. Example:

```
<form action="export.php" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="param1">
    <input type="text" name="param2">
    ...
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Your CSV exporting script needs little modification: it should process the query string variables to build the query. Something like:

```
$where = "1 = 1";
if ($param1 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "param1"))
{
    $where .= " AND param1 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($param1) . "'";
}
if ($param2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "param2"))
{
    $where .= " AND param2 = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($param2) . "'";
}
...
$query = sprintf( 'SELECT * FROM hostess WHERE $where' );
```

When you submit the form, it will request the export page passing the parameters in the query string (e.g. export.php?param1=foo&param2=bar). The script will dispatch a CSV file. The `target=_blank` attribute is added on the form so that the CSV file is loaded in a new tab/window.

Comment: +1 you should definitely get this one, seeing as you wrote the script in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Set up another page with the link. That way, you can link to the CSV file from any page.

Comment: Yes sure, but  in the query i need to insert a variable which i take from a form, which means i need to put something like this: Select $checked from hostess etc etc.. and the checked variable i get it from somewhere..

Comment: Use an HTML form. Then use `$_GET('whatever')` to access the variables.

Comment: hey ok, but how can i do in order to download the csv file only if i link it.. not immediately..

Comment: @GazetaAlmedicus: you can make a form and post your needed content to that link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: You have to make a form in the new page that will allow the user to put in the variable. Then, make the "action" attribute of the form equal to your PHP's URL. Use [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formex.php) tutorial.

Comment: the problem is that i already connected that form with a php file, on submit i get the query, i just need to print the query as a table then download this query as csv... I don't know if i'm being clear...if i'm explaining myself...

Comment: I think what you want is AJAX. Is that what you're trying to do?